# Sympy: Get functions from expression

Tags: python, sympy

To get all variables from a sympy expression, one can call `.free_symbols` on the expression. I would like to retrieve all *functions* used in an expression. For example, from `y` in

```
from sympy import *

f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

x = Symbol('x')

y = f(x) + 2*g(x)
```

I'd like to get `f` and `g`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all functions, use `atoms(Function)`.

```
In [40]: (f(x) + sin(x)).atoms(Function)
Out[40]: set([f(x), sin(x)])
```

For only undefined functions, use `atoms(AppliedUndef)`.

```
In [41]: from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef

In [42]: (f(x) + sin(x)).atoms(AppliedUndef)
Out[42]: set([f(x)])
```

Answer (score 7):

`atoms` does the trick:

```
for f in y.atoms(Function):
    print(f.func)
```