# How to find free symbols *and* undefined functions in a SymPy expression?

Tags: python, sympy

I am wondering how to find the symbols connected with [Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122871/5661667) in a sympy expression. I am aware of [`.free_symbols`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019034/5661667), [`.atoms(Function)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629624/5661667) as well as [`.atoms(AppliedUndef)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629624/5661667). Here is some code to show why none of these does what I need.

```
f1 = Function(r'f_1')
f2 = Function(r'f_2')
c1, x = symbols(r'c_1, x')

expr = c1+f1(x)+f2(x)
print(expr)
# c_1 + f_1(x) + f_2(x)
print(expr.free_symbols)
# {x, c_1}
print(expr.atoms(Function))
# {f_1(x), f_2(x)}

from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
print(expr.atoms(AppliedUndef))
# {f_1(x), f_2(x)}
```

(The comments are the outputs of each print line). So `.free_symbols` is nice, it gives me `c_1` and `x`. However, it does not return the symbols associated with the functions `f_1` and `f_2`. (First question: why? Are they not free somehow?). `.atoms(Function)` does not help either. It finds the functions, but does not return their associated symbols (e.g. `f_1`), it returns the whole function call (e.g. `f_1(x)`).

**Main question:** How do I find the symbols `f_1` and `f_2` in above expression?

Background: The reason I want this, is because I would like to [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) in the following way

```
expr_num = lambdify([c1, f1, f2, x], expr)
```

but instead of giving the argument `[c1, f1, f2, x]` manually, I would like to find all necessary symbols in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following obtains free symbols and names of AppliedUndef functions:

```
>>> s = f(x).free_symbols
>>> func = set([i.func for i in f(x).atoms(Function) if isinstance(i, AppliedUndef)])
>>> s | func
{x, f}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This would solve my problem, but does not run for me. Your code with the definitions of x and f from the question: `x = symbols(r'x')
f = Function(r'f')
s = f(x).free_symbols
func = set([i.name for i in f(x).atoms(Function) if isinstance(i, AppliedUndef)])
s | func` gives `AttributeError: 'f' object has no attribute 'name'`. Indeed `f(x).name` gives the same error.

Comment: You might have an old version of SymPy. I updated the answer to use 'func' instead of 'name' since the latter would give a string instead of the function 'f'.

Comment: The new version with '.func' even works in my sympy version. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted [solution by @smichr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258497/5661667), here is a piece of code that can be directly appended to the code in the question (adds nothing interesting, just for convenience):

```
f1 = Function(r'f_1')
f2 = Function(r'f_2')
c1, x = symbols(r'c_1, x')

syms_and_funs = set(expr.free_symbols) | set([i.func for i in expr.atoms(Function) if isinstance(i, AppliedUndef)])
print(syms_and_funs)
# {x, f_2, f_1, c_1}

expr_num = lambdify(syms_and_funs, expr)
```